# Стандартный Wallpaper в прграмме

Tags: xcode, objective-c, iphone

Насколько я понимаю то я могу юзнуть на фон стандартные картинки, которые есть в iPhone/iPad

pict.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stars"];

Stars - это стандартная картинка. Которая была еще в рекламе iOS7=) Как назваются остальные картинки, где можно найти их названия ???

Comment: результат [UIImage imageNamed:@"Stars"] = (null), что вполне логично, так как подобное не должно быть возможно никак

Comment: Не заю как там null может быть :) у меня там фон неба звездного )))